# Visual Studio Theme - Change operator highlight active color

Tags: visual-studio-2012, themes, visual-studio-2015

I want to change the highlight/active color for operators in visual studio 2015 using the color theme editor extension. What do I search for to change this?

I see Text Editor > Operator > Background color

But this changes the background color always - not just on highlight.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Near the top-left, click the double-list icon (Show all elements),
  and search for 'operator', which should show you a field called
  Text Editor -> Operator -> Foreground; you want the hex for FG color to be FF839496.

Comment: I saw that, although what I'm looking for is the "active" state or when I click on it. The default theme highlights the background of operators to a light grey. That's what I want to change.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out! Hopefully it's the same in VS2012 as it is in 2015, which I am using.

The setting is Environment > Fonts and Colors > Text Editor > Brace Matching.

[image]